# Startech SVx41HDI Series Server Remote Control Usage Question - How do I switch away from a dead port?

Tags: remote-access, keyboard, keyboard-video-mouse

We have a Startech KVM over IP model SV841HDI and it was stuck pointing a port where the machine has been removed.  We ended up having to physically plug something into that port in order to switch ports again, meaning that if someone in support accidentally switches to an empty port, we need to have a documented solution for making it useable again.

The unit is old, no longer under warranty, firmware updates for it are no longer available (interestingly it runs a powerPC version of busybox).  Since it does work well except for this one catch, we would like to avoid replacing it.

Reading the manual, you have a several recommended methods. I tried them.  Hit the left CTRL key a few times (as well as all the other popular KVM keys I could think of). The VNC GUI offers lots of buttons - none of them switch away from a dead port.

The question is: how do I switch away from a dead port on this particular KVM remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to test this just to make sure it doesn't FREAK IT OUT... but you could try plugging in a simple loopback plug in.  RJ-45 plug, simple: connect pins 1-6, 2-3 gigabit: also connect 4-7 and 5-8.

If you need a picture or more specific instructions on how to make one use the googles.

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=rj45+loopback+plug+pinout

In theory this should make it think there's a connection and allow you to move on.

Comment: The input connectors on this model are VGA (DSUB-15), PS/2 Mouse and PS/2 Keyboard.  I like the idea of a loop back device, but I am a bit shy to try it on these input ports.  This does give me an idea to try though, since most of the other non-IP KVM's I have used draw power from the keyboard ports, it might just be a matter of plugging the loose PS/2 keyboard plug into a spare PS/2 port on a mother board.

Comment: Ahh yes - most of those older ones that are kvm inputs depend on the keyboard (since it's powered) to make it think something is there.  Sorry I didn't pay enough attention I thought it was one of the rj45 models.